# Azure IOT ServiceClient / RegistryClient: What is the recommended frequency of CloseAsync?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

`Microsoft.Azure.Devices.ServiceClient` and `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.RegistryManager` both have `ConnectFromConnectionString` and `CloseAsync` methods.

Should we use them like we use other .NET `connection-close` patterns, such as ADO.NET connections, Redis connections, Sockets' etc.?   When I use objects like those I try to `Close` or `Disposable.Dispose()` of them as soon as possible.

What's the upside and downside to doing the same with the `Microsoft.Azure.Devices` objects when accessing the same IOT Hub?  I have running code that treats the individual `RegistryManager` and `ServiceClient` instances as singletons, which are used throughout an application's lifetime -- which may be weeks or months.  Are we short circuiting ourselves by keeping these objects "open" for this duration?

Comment: Close and reopen will cost some time if it is not a problem for you, close them when they are will not be used for a long time and reopen when it is needed.

Comment: Rita - or anyone - can you confirm that keeping the connections open for weeks or months won't itself lead to a memory or other leak that will destabilize our application?

Does anyone have any data on how-fast or slow re-opening the connections would be? Is closing/re-opening actually an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @David R. Williamson, and [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/706), it is generally recommended to register `RegistryManager` and `ServiceClient` as singletons.

For ASP NET Core or Azure Functions, it can be done as follows at startup:

```cs
ConfigureServices(services)
{
  services.AddSingleton<RegistryManager>(RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString("connectionstring"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the Azure IoT SDK team. We recommend keeping the service client instances around, depending on your usage pattern.

While it is generally fine to init/close/dispose the Azure IoT service clients, you can run into the [HttpClient socket exhaustion problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/). We've done work to prevent it from happening if you keep a singleton of the client around, but when the client is disposed [2 HttpClient instances are also disposed](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/main/common/src/service/HttpClientHelper.cs#L736-L737).

There's little harm in keeping them around and will save your program execution time in init/dispose.

We're working on a v2 where we'll allow the user to pass in their own copy of HttpClient, so you could keep that around and shut down our client more frequently.